# How to interpret macOS's memory information from the kernel?

Tags: c, macos, memory, kernel

I wrote a little piece of C code that retrieves the current memory status from the macOS kernel and prints it to `stdout`.

```c
#include <_types/_uint64_t.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct memory {
  host_t host;
  mach_msg_type_number_t count;
  vm_statistics64_data_t vm_stat;

  char command[256];
};

static inline void memory_init(struct memory *memory) {
  memory->host = mach_host_self();
  snprintf(memory->command, 100, "");
  printf("Free\t\tActive\t\tIntr.\t\tWired.\t\tPurgable.\tSpec.\n");
}

long double pagesToGB(natural_t pages) {
    uint64_t pages_u = (uint64_t)pages;
    uint64_t pageSize = (uint64_t)getpagesize();
    long double kB = (pages_u * pageSize) / 1024.;
    return kB / 1024. / 1024;
}

static inline void memory_update(struct memory *memory) {
  memory->count = HOST_VM_INFO64_COUNT;
  kern_return_t error =
      host_statistics64(memory->host, HOST_VM_INFO64, (host_info64_t)&memory->vm_stat,
                      &memory->count);

  if (error != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("Error: Could not read memory host statistics. Error code: %u\n", error);
    return;
  }

  long double freeMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.free_count);
  long double activeMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.active_count);
  long double interactiveMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.inactive_count);
  long double wiredMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.wire_count);
  long double purgableMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.purgeable_count);
  long double speculativeMemGB = pagesToGB(memory->vm_stat.speculative_count);

  printf("%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\t%Lf\n", freeMemGB, activeMemGB, interactiveMemGB, wiredMemGB, purgableMemGB, speculativeMemGB);

}

int main() {
  struct memory m;
  memory_init(&m);
  while (1) {
    memory_update(&m);
    usleep(1000000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the executable looks something like this:

```
Free        Active      Intr.       Wired.      Purgable.   Spec.
2.795090    5.505280    5.094604    1.539963    0.443802    0.346817
2.791519    5.453690    5.102158    1.585968    0.420609    0.346817
2.792435    5.524200    5.108643    1.508865    0.423462    0.346817
2.791977    5.534302    5.130783    1.476685    0.426575    0.346741
2.793686    5.507736    5.123581    1.508850    0.424347    0.346741
```

But the Activity Monitor says:

```
Memory Used:
 - App Memory:    5.93 GB
 - Wired Memory:  1.44 GB
 - Compressed:   420.8 MB
Cached Files:     6.XX GB
```

The values just don't add up... I also attached a picture were you can see the exact numbers.

[image]

None of the values printed by the above code seem to make any sense i.e. there seems to be no way how to combine them to find any of the values displayed in the Activity Monitor (most importantly for used memory...).

Can somebody explain to me what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: Please post code, data, **and results** as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Do you want `host_statistics64` instead? Also, the final argument is an "input/output": _On input, the maximum size of the buffer; on output, the size returned (in natural-sized units)._ So, maybe you should move `memory->count = HOST_VM_INFO_COUNT;` to the first line of the update function. And, it may be fine, but I'm having a little difficulty with the casting and precedence of the body of `pagesToGB`

Comment: @Barmar Added a description mentioning all the data to the question.

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks a lot for the input. I implemented your suggestions and changed the code above to reflect that. The result is still the same, but now we know it's not due to the fact I did not use the 64 bit version or the precedence. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't really have a good answer for you as I don't have access to a mac. But ... This may help: [Why does host_statistics64() return inconsistent results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14789672/5382650) Also, for [some of] the OS kernel source Apple's github https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions In particular, the XNU kernel: https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu Under that, look at: `osfmk/kern/host.c` It has the _kernel_ source for the `host_statistics` and `host_statistics64` syscalls.

Comment: Shouldn't Intr./Interactive be Inac./Inactive instead, or is that wording expected?